# Turing Machine for $\{a^n b^n c^n | n \ge0\}$

Tags: automata, turing-machines

I have tried making a Turing machine for $\{a^n b^n c^n | n \ge 0\}$
for $n \ge 1$ it was easy, but for $n = 0$, I have added one more transition.
Please check and tell if this is correct.

Or tell for which strings it may fail.

[image: Turing Machine]